# ObjC - Post a UIImage by using NSData and NSURLRequest?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit

I'm trying to post an image to TwitPic.com using their API.

However, I have never posted an image using HTTPPOST or however else before.

Anybody enlighten me to how I can post NSData from a UIImage using their api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TwitPic is expecting a [multi-part form data](http://www.twitpic.com/api.do#uploadAndPost). There is a great open source library called [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

You can use their APIs and post your image as multi-part/form-data.

See below for the sample.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: Cheers for that. However, I still get a crash.. This is what I have got:

http://pastie.org/445027

Comment: In the linked code, you passed the data instead of the file path for the "media" parameter.  I see there's also a setData:forKey: method, which maybe you can use without writing out to a file first.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `UIImagePNGRepresentation` function or its JPEG equivalent to turn a UIImage into an NSData:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation

Answer (score 1):

@Jamie:

Try:

[request setData:twitpicImage forKey:@"media"];

If the image view is actually displaying an image that is stored in a file on disk, use:

[request setFile:theImagePath forKey:@"media"];

This way, ASIHTTPRequest will stream the image data from disk, so you don't have to keep an NSData instance in memory.

Ta

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setPostValue for the image, use setData instead.